# Over overloaded method

Tags: c#, overloading, signalr

I am using SignalR to send notifications to clients. I use `IClientProxy` which is a proxy for invoking hub methods.

It has 10 overload methods for `SendAsync` that takes parameters one by one as you see below, however, to handle this situation I have written a spagetti style method which is really weird to me.

Could you please give some suggestion?

```cs
private async Task InvokeNotification(string userName, string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{
    if (connections.ContainsKey(userName))
    {
        var proxy = Clients.Clients(connections[userName]);
        switch (parameters.Length)
        {
            case 0:
                await proxy.SendAsync(methodName);
                break;

            case 1:
                await proxy.SendAsync(methodName, parameters[0]);
                break;

            case 2:
                await proxy.SendAsync(methodName, parameters[0], parameters[1]);
                break;

            default:
                throw new HubException($"No method was defined with {parameters.Length} parameters in Hub");
        }
    }
}
```

The following code block is the definition of SendAsync which is coming from SignalR

```cs
public static class ClientProxyExtensions
{
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3, object arg4, object arg5, object arg6, object arg7, object arg8, object arg9, object arg10, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3, object arg4, object arg5, object arg6, object arg7, object arg8, object arg9, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3, object arg4, object arg5, object arg6, object arg7, object arg8, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3, object arg4, object arg5, object arg6, object arg7, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3, object arg4, object arg5, object arg6, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3, object arg4, object arg5, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3, object arg4, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object arg1, object arg2, object arg3, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object arg1, object arg2, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, object arg1, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
    public static Task SendAsync(this IClientProxy clientProxy, string method, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `SendAsync` method overloads? Does it apply `params` too? If it is, you may pass parameters as array there.

Comment: @aepot , I updated the code

Comment: Is `connections` a kind of `Dictionary`? I can suggest one more improvement then.

Comment: Yes it is, please shot!

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for me, this code is fine. Maybe there's some `Reflection` dark magic available but this one will be anyway faster.

The only thing I can suggest here is optimizing out an `async` State Machine because there's no code after `await` and the only await in the method can be executed.

Also note that you lookup through the `Dictionary` twice, first time when you check key with `.ContainsKey`, second time when you get the value with the same key. It can be done with single lookup using `Dictionary.TryGetValue()` method.

Also I suggest to follow `async` naming policy suggested by Microsoft, and rename the method to `InvokeNotificationAsync`.

```csharp
private Task InvokeNotificationAsync(string userName, string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{
    if (connections.TryGetValue(userName, out var connection))
    {
        var proxy = Clients.Clients(connection);
        switch (parameters.Length)
        {
            case 0:
                return proxy.SendAsync(methodName);
                break;

            case 1:
                return proxy.SendAsync(methodName, parameters[0]);
                break;

            case 2:
                return proxy.SendAsync(methodName, parameters[0], parameters[1]);
                break;

            default:
                throw new HubException($"No method was defined with {parameters.Length} parameters in Hub");
        }
    }
}
```

Also it can look a bit better with C# 8.0 syntax

```csharp
private Task InvokeNotificationAsync(string userName, string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{
    if (connections.TryGetValue(userName, out var connection))
    {
        var proxy = Clients.Clients(connection);
        return parameters.Length switch
        {
            0 => proxy.SendAsync(methodName),
            1 => proxy.SendAsync(methodName, parameters[0]),
            2 => proxy.SendAsync(methodName, parameters[0], parameters[1]),
            _ => throw new HubException($"No method was defined with {parameters.Length} parameters in Hub")
        };
    }
}
```